# How to include only project and relocated classes when using Gradle Shadow plugin?

Tags: gradle, gradle-shadow-plugin

I have the following:

```
shadowJar {
    relocate 'com.google.common', 'com.example.com.google.common'
}
```

which produces '-all.jar' files with all of the module's dependencies.

```
shadowJar {
    relocate 'com.google.common', 'com.example.com.google.common'

    dependencies {
        include('com.example.com.google.common')
    }
}
```

and:

```
shadowJar {
    relocate 'com.google.common', 'com.example.com.google.common'

    dependencies {
        include(dependency('com.google.guava:guava:14+'))
    }
}
```

both produce '-all.jar' files with absolutely no classes.

How do I go about creating the '-all.jar' files that includes only the project's classes and the relocated classes?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify guava in the shadow configuration. For example:

```
dependencies {
    shadow 'com.google.guava:guava:14+'
}
```